# Nav bar is hiding application bottom tool bar in all apps

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I have a Lumia 635 with Windows 10 Mobile Version 1607 OS. build 10.0.14393.67

I now have a problem where in all apps with a tool bar along the bottom which is being hidden by the navigation bar... I have tried rotating screen to see if this helps but even though I have rotation lock off... the screen does not rotate.

How can I get the toolbar to be visible on top of the nav bar like it used to be?

As requested an example from Calendar... but all apps with a toolbar are affected.

[image]

The bottom of the screenshot shows that half the toolbar is obscured by the navbar which does not show in a screenshot.

The problem is that often it is difficult to click on the toolbar icons as the system thinks you have clicked on one of the nav bar icons. E.G. in the above example if I try and click the + icon to add a new calendar entry I get the start page as the nav bar windows icon is in the same area.

Comment: Perhaps you could include a screenshot to illustrate?

Comment: What if you restart or reset factory settings of the phone?

Comment: Had to wait until I was not on-call to try factory reset as I rely on my phone so much. Facotory reset did not make any difference still the same :(